# Seemingly wrong information from Mage::getStoreConfig

Tags: magento-enterprise

I'll spare everyone the drudgery of why, but I have a script here that should create an invoice for an order and send that invoice email. It works fine, except the email isn't going out.

I've dug into it a while and it seems it's a problem with finding the config value for sales_email/invoice/enabled. I wrote a script to just get the information for that path for a given store, and it seems to be always return true, even when I've disabled it. Some stores appear to be the opposite.

Enough talk, here's the code:

magetestconfig.php

```
<?php

require_once '/var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$path = $argv[1];
$store = $argv[2];

$result = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($path, $store);
$resultFlag = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($path, $store);
echo "The path is $path, store is $store, results are ($result,$resultFlag)".PHP_EOL;
```

Running that gives me:

```
The path is sales_email/invoice/enabled, store is 2, results are (1,1)
```

Yet, in admin it's disabled for that store, and this seems to be accurately reflected in the database:

```
mysql> select scope,scope_id,path,value from core_config_data where path like '%invoice/enabled%' and scope_id = 2;
+----------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
| scope    | scope_id | path                        | value |
+----------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
| websites |        2 | sales_email/invoice/enabled | 0     |
+----------+----------+-----------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The only time I've noticed this problem is in this script, run in a terminal, but I don't see how that would matter, but I haven't had to do this particular thing before, so it's entirely possible I just missed something.

As a bit of a disclaimer, I am overwriting some classes for what I'm working on, but nothing that I can imagine affecting this, but if no one has ideas with this, it could just be that I'm wrong on that assumption. I am not overwriting anything related to the site config, though, only a few things with with store emails, which is (other than this) working correctly.

**Edit**: Here's another example.

```
<?php

require_once '/var/www/html/magento/shell/abstract.php';

class Mage_Shell_Configtest extends Mage_Shell_Abstract {
    public function run() {  
        $path = "sales_email/invoice/template";
        $template = Mage::getStoreConfig($path, 2);
        echo "Template: $template".PHP_EOL;

        echo "The path is '$path'".PHP_EOL;
        echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------".PHP_EOL;
        echo "Store | getStoreConfig()                            | getStoreConfigFlag()".PHP_EOL;
        echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------------".PHP_EOL;
        foreach (range(1,13) as $store) {
            $result = Mage::getStoreConfig($path, $store);
            $resultFlag = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag($path, $store);
            printf(" %4s | %-43s | %s \n",$store,$result,$resultFlag);
        }
    }

    public function usageHelp() {
        return "Run it.";
    }
}

$shell = new Mage_Shell_Configtest();
$shell->run();
```

This gives:

```
Template: sales_email_invoice_template
The path is 'sales_email/invoice/template'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Store | getStoreConfig()                            | getStoreConfigFlag()
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
    2 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
    3 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
    4 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
    5 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
    6 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
    7 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
    8 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
    9 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
   10 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
   11 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
   12 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
   13 | sales_email_invoice_template                | 1
```

But checking the database shows:

```
mysql> select scope,scope_id,path,value from core_config_data where path like '%invoice/template%';
+----------+----------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| scope    | scope_id | path                         | value                        |
+----------+----------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| default  |        0 | sales_email/invoice/template | sales_email_invoice_template |
| websites |        2 | sales_email/invoice/template | 10                           |
+----------+----------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was barking up the wrong tree entirely. The problem had nothing to do with code, it was that I was running these scripts as my own user, rather than as something like 'apache' - I'm guessing it was an issue with file permissions and the cache. As soon as I just tried running it with sudo, everything worked properly.